# Extract Uniques and loop

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A  B          C
0  1  2  PRODUCT_1
1  3  2  PRODUCT_2
2  3  2  PRODUCT_4
3  3  2  PRODUCT_5
4  5  2  PRODUCT_1
5  3  2  PRODUCT_3
```

I want to, for each unique product, perform a model prediction with A and B columns, and store the corresponding accuracy.

```
unique = ["PRODUCT_1", ...] # unique products
accuracy
for i in unique:
    first_subset = ???  # all rows for product `i` - how do I implement this correctly?

X = first_subset[:, 0]
Y = first_subset[:, 1]

prediction_product_1 = model.predict(X)
accuracy_product_1 = np.sum( (prediction_product_1)/np.sum(Y) )    
accuracy.append([accuracy_product_1, PRODUCT_1])
```

How could I implement the second point in Python?

Comment: Where is your code that you're struggling with?

Comment: take a close looke at `df.groupby`. This generates groups or smaller `DataFrames` for each unique key

Comment: I can't correctly initialize the loop and create a frame for the last point, since I'm not an advanced coder @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Okay, can't you at least provide a [mcve] with sample data and output? You're working with pandas aren't you? How do you expect to get an answer without providing anything?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) are some more tips for a clear question

Comment: Thank you; I tried my best to make it more clear @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: I cleaned your question up, it was badly in need of some work. See my answer for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...) # your data 
df

   A  B          C
0  1  2  PRODUCT_1
1  3  2  PRODUCT_2
2  3  2  PRODUCT_4
3  3  2  PRODUCT_5
4  5  2  PRODUCT_1
5  3  2  PRODUCT_3
```

Find uniques first, using

```
uniques = df.C.unique()

uniques
array(['PRODUCT_1', 'PRODUCT_2', 'PRODUCT_4', 'PRODUCT_5', 'PRODUCT_3'], dtype=object)
```

To get all rows from a particular product, I'd do this using `groupby` (so, you actually don't need `uniques` here) -

```
acc = {}
for i, g in df.groupby('C'):
    X, y = g['A'], g['B']
    p = model.predict(X, y)

    acc[i] = (p == y).sum() / len(y)
```

Basically, for each group, call `model.predict` and append a key-value pair to the `acc` dict.

Comment: how could it be addressed using numpy instead?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli If you want a numpy answer, don't tag the question pandas. Also, a numpy solution may not be as efficient or easy to achieve.

Comment: Okay, but whenever I try to run the code, it report me an error at the last line  acc[i] = ..." list assignment index out of range" ;  could it be because I have not called an "append" command yet?

Comment: @AlessandroCeccarelli No did you see the top of the loop? I've defined `acc` as `{}`, not `[]`.